# Problem opening a large .doc file

Tags: 10.10, libreoffice, word-documents

I am trying to open a 33 page xxx.doc file which has data in in a table (3 coloumns X 200+ rows) using Libre Office 3.3.2. The files take ~4-6 minutes to open (all other applications and smaller documents  opens real fast and I have a new and fast laptop). During this time entire LibreOffice will appears as hung.  I checked swap usage using free and I can see it used some swap, but very little.

Once I open the document, I do see the data and table alignment completely lost. There are some areas table has contents, but by and large data is not within the cells as expected.

How I can speed up the opening process and how I can get the data almost like when I open with MS-Office?

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you provide a .doc file so that people can try reproducing your problem in coming up with a solution.

Comment: Do you know a way to link/upload a large sized file to this question ? Then I can do it. I could not figure out a way and http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1491/ask-ubuntu-and-file-attachments indicates that I may not be able to.

Comment: If you've got Ubuntu One (if not it's free) you can upload it there. You right-click the file and choose Ubuntu One - Publish. After that you'll be able to get an URL for the file from the same menu.

Answer (score 1):

This is does not help you with LibreOffice but it might help you opening and working more efficiently with your document. Have you tried to instead open your document in **[AbiWord](http://www.abisource.com/)**? AbiWord is a word processor that is lighter and faster than LibreOffice

Comment: No. I did not, but I will wait  to see if I have solution to this before trying other office packages.

Comment: @Jamess See [LibreOffice or OpenOffice?](http://www.petermoulding.com/libreoffice_or_openoffice) for a comparison of word processors.